# Modifying binary output before returning to the prompt mode

Tags: linux, bash

I have a binary which prints a question and then waits for a user answer.
I have no access to the source code of this binary, but I want to modify the screen output.

Example:

```
> ./commandx 
 Day 1
 Day 2
 Day 3
 Please type the number:
```

I want to display:

```
Night 1
Night 2
Night 3
Please type the number:
```

The pipe solution does not work in this case.

Comment: Which "pipe solution" did you try and what was the output? Have you tried piping `STDERR` through `sed`?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Sorry, missed your comment. Your suggestion was right, I redirected the STDERR to STDOUT and then edited it by sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First I've investigated the binary with strace command and found that it printed the output to STDERR instead STDOUT. Then I used the redirection to STDOUT and the pipe command start to work.

```
./commandx 2>&1 | perl -pe  's/Day/Night/g'
```